# Automatic linux-headers installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, aptitude

Is there a way to get the matching Linux kernel headers automatic on a regular kernel update via the Ubuntu packed manager?

Every time I get a new kernel I must do an

```
aptitude install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you installed `linux-headers-generic` or `linux-headers-386`? Those meta-packages keep track of the installed kernel and get updated automagically when a new kernel (and hence a kernel-header) package is available.

See [the ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages#Kernel%20Metapackages) for further information.

Comment: `linux-headers-generic` does not exist anymore in Debian 10. You need to install `linux-headers-amd64`. I was having trouble with missing headers for `virtualbox`. This answer comes at the top of a Google search about automatically installing headers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug #693311 of automatic updater. This bug is not solved. I verify that linux-headers-generic is installed (Ubuntu 12.10) but it is not helpful. For more information see:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/693311